# set scroll view that contains views and stack view doesn't fit on simulator . iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hi every one actually I want to fit this scroll view and stack views on simulator correctly but unfortunately this result not things that I design to view controller and here is my constraints :

[image]

if you have any idea , please share thank you so much.

here is when I result after the answer :

[image]

Comment: There is nothing we can do to suggest correct layout constraints, I suggest you google on how to use stack view and scroll view together in storyboard.

Comment: yes always try to solve matters with watching movies and searches before stack over flow

Answer (score 0):

The problem is **Stack View.height = height**, StackView's height should be automatically driven by it's subviews.

[image]

After you remove this, you should see another issue that's caused by **Stack View.centerY = centerY** - you should be able to remove this as well and you should get the expected behavior with rest of the constraints in place.

**UPDATE** :
From the screenshot, it appears that you are using **Distribution = Fill Proportionally** for the `StackView`, and it will require a height constraint to distribute it's children proportionally within that height. You should use **Distribution = Fill** and it will NOT require the height constraint anymore.

**UPDATE 2** :
According to the 2nd screenshot, your `ScrollView` height is not defined. You should set something like **ScrollView.bottom = superview.bottom** which will tell `ScrollView` how tall it needs to be. Once your `ScrollView` height is defined, it should go away.

Comment: thank you brother , but after I removed Stack View.height = height I dont have error but still in my simulator it doesnt fit correctly

Comment: Did you also remove **Stack View.centerY = centerY**  as I suggested in the answer?

Comment: yes after I removed Stack View.height = height I removed Stack View.centerY = centerY as well too and I got error like this : "need constraints for : y position or height " that I can choose add missing constrains

Comment: See the **UPDATE** to the answer - You should use **Distribution = Fill** for the `StackView`.

Comment: See **UPDATE 2** in the answer.

Comment: sorry I dont have a result that I wanted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233173/discussion-between-ali-kazemi-and-tarun-tyagi).